# Broken enum equality (with powermock)

Tags: java, testing, enums, mockito, powermock

With this enum:

```
public enum Testnum {
    A("a"), B("b");

    String x;

    private Testnum(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

The assertFalse in this test fails:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("Testnum")
public class EnumTest {

    @Test
    public void mainSuccess() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Testnum.class);

        assertFalse(Testnum.A == Testnum.B);
    }
}
```

Any idea why / how I can work around this?

Comment: Why do you expect this behavior to be the sort of thing you could change with mocking at all?  (Why would you ever even think about mocking this behavior?)

Comment: Change what with mocking? I don't want any behaviour to change, I want enum equality checks to still work. I need the mocking annotations for code not present in this test case.

Comment: First: Mocking an Enum is wrong. Very very wrong. Either your enum is doing to much or your looking at your test wrong.

Comment: Secondly, when you say "fails", fails how? As I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class Testnum` with the code above as you have not prepared the enum for testing. `@PrepareForTest(Testnum.class)`